# Refreshing UITableView Asynchronously after Core Data Loaded Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a UITableView, `tViewNews`

I have a refresh function which downloads data from my server, stores it into core data, and then the table view loads this data from core data.

It works perfectly

```
func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    self.newsArray = [NewsItem]()
    self.newslists = [[NewsItem]]()
    self.getNewsFromServer()
    self.getNewsFromCoreData()
    self.tViewNews.reloadData()

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Now, when the user first opens the news `viewDidLoad()`, I would like for the table view to first load from the core data, then asynchronously populate my table view array from the server (using precisely the same method as the refresh function) and then reload the table view.

So I have tried the following code in my `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Getting news from Core Data
    getNewsFromCoreData()

    // Updating core data from server and populating table view from core data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        self.newsArray = [NewsItem]()
        self.newslists = [[NewsItem]]()
        self.getNewsFromServer()
        self.getNewsFromCoreData()
        self.tViewNews.reloadData()

    }
```

As you can see the functions being run inside the async request are identical to those inside the refresh function.

But!, the refresh function functions properly, populating and reloading the table view. But the async request does absolutely nothing. The table view remains empty. But the functions are running, as tested with print statements.

Anyone know why this is the case?

**EDIT - Added extra fucntions**

**Get Core Data**

```
func getNewsFromCoreData() {
    let temp = StaffCoreData()
    temp.getAllNews()

    newsDates = Dictionary<Int, [NewsItem]>()

    for newsobj in temp.newsArray{

        if var curdate = newsDates[toNewsItem(newsobj).age]{

            curdate.append(toNewsItem(newsobj))
            newsDates[toNewsItem(newsobj).age] = curdate


        }else{

            newsDates[toNewsItem(newsobj).age] = [toNewsItem(newsobj)]

        }
    }

    for var i = 0; i<50; ++i{if let curdate = newsDates[i]{newslists.append(curdate)}}
```

**Get Server Data**

runs instance with following method:

```
func NewsCallReturnsWithSuccess(data: NSData) {

    if let jsonObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) {
        if let statusesArray = jsonObject as? NSArray{

            newsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for item in statusesArray {
                let datacon : NSData = item.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                let jsonObject : NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(datacon, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                let title : NSString = jsonObject.objectForKey("title") as! NSString
                let content : NSString = jsonObject.objectForKey("content") as! NSString
                let publishedby : NSString = jsonObject.objectForKey("publishedby") as! NSString
                let modified : NSString = jsonObject.objectForKey("modified") as! NSString
                let imageurl : NSString = jsonObject.objectForKey("imageurl") as! NSString
                let category : NSString = jsonObject.objectForKey("category") as! NSString

                let newsItem = NewsItem(title: title as String, content: content as String, category: category as String, imageURL: imageurl as String, publishedBy: publishedby as String, modified: modified as String)

                newsArray.append(newsItem)
                }

            //add complete array to CoreData
            let temp = StaffCoreData()
            temp.addArrayOfNew(newsArray)

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How does your getNewsFromServer and getNewsFromCoreData work. Do they fetch content in background thread ?

Answer (score 3):

When you are using a different thread for loading your data, you have to return to the main thread when finished loading to update the UI.

Like:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        // load data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // update ui
        }
    }
```

UPDATE

Pls show us your `getNewsFromCoreData()` and `getNewsFromServer()` methods and maybe your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, too.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        // load data
        self.newsArray = [NewsItem]()
        self.newslists = [[NewsItem]]()
        self.getNewsFromServer()
        self.getNewsFromCoreData()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // update ui
            self.tViewNews.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still get the same error. Is it possible for me to do this: On `viewDidLoad()` I populate table view from core Data. Then I run the refresh function straight away, automatically and asynchronously without actually calling the refresh function. Or equivalent?

Comment: Thanks! I have added some more to the question. However, there is too much code to look through if I was to post all of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and other functions. Hopefully what I posted above gives you the gist. The important thing to note is that the refresh function works perfectly and I would just like to have that run automatically and asynchronously on startup.

Comment: Ok. Most important is, that you can load your data asynchronously but you have to update your table view on the main thread. Assuming your data loading works properly follow my edited answer. Do you get the same error when loading the data synchronously (without GCD) in viewDidLoad()?

Comment: To help narrow down the problem, when i put `println(self.newslists[0].count)` directly after `self.getNewsFromCoreData()` I get an index out of range error. Meaning these methods are clearly not functioning properly. But why do they work in the refresh function, but not here !?! That's what has me confused

Comment: So I don't think the problem is with the table view updating on the main thread. I don't know a whole lot about GCD either I'm very new to this.

Comment: Hard to say... I guess you are not storing your loaded data correctly in your list of news arrays. You are using newslists to populate your table view, right? Where do you set newslists?

Comment: newslists is populated from CoreData. I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Thanks for all the help anyway, I know it's difficult reading through all the code, and even more so because I haven't revealed all of it.